# Tkinter Menu makes no Tab [Windows only]

Tags: python, tabs, tkinter, menubar

Well, I coded a menu bar into my Python program and I wanted to make a tab in the menu-item-description.
My code:

```
myMenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=myMenu)

menu1 = Menu(myMenu)
myMenu.add_cascade(label='Optionen', menu=menu1)
menu1.add_command(label='Informationen' '\t' 'F5', command = info)
menu1.add_command(label='Beenden' '\t' '\t' 'esc', command = ende)
```

It works perfectly on UNIX (Ubuntu & Mac OS X) but **Windows** doesn't work!
[image: No tabs..]

Hope someone can help! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are out of luck. Menus in Tkinter are native, so you're at the mercy of Microsoft.

If you're trying to provide a string that represents an accelerator, use the `accelerator` attribute instead of faking it with a tab in the label.

```
menu1.add_command(label='Informationen', command = info, accelerator="F5")
menu1.add_command(label='Beenden', command = ende, accelerator="esc")
```

Comment: @Leo: "esc" should display if you did it right; it displays for me on windows just fine. There's nothing special about "esc" that would prevent it from being displayed.